# Next JS 13 App Project is very slow to save file and showing intellisense suggestions in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, tailwind-css, intellisense, next.js13

I had this issue when developing a project of Next JS 13 app stable version in VS Code. The longer I run my app in dev mode the longer it takes for save, for intellicode to loads suggestions, also for prettier and eslint to auto format.

Example case:

1. I stay and edits many times in one page.tsx file, which means nextjswill compile many times as well.
2. As time goes on, the slow loading of saving and formatting comes up.
3. The slow loading comes up more clear especially after I move to another file
4. In the end I tried to restart VSCode and run dev again.
5. At beginning after restart everything goes fine, but as time goes on... back to point number 1.

This is very strange bug because only in this Next JS 13 app project that the lags happen. Meanwhile I also opened other project like React project and Next JS 13 pages project, these projects run just fine.

For now still not yet found the solution, already tried to add .next in tsconfig and disabling extension just as the github community suggested, but lag still occurs.

Comment: Did you try deleting the `.next` folder?

Comment: I've tried to delete ``.next`` folder yet still facing the issue

Answer (score 3):

I decided to experiment with Next.js 13.4 to see if it would be a good fit for my project. In a simple React Vite app, I had a basic form that worked perfectly fine. However, after recreating it in Next.js, the development mode became extremely slow. As you mentioned, even the compilation time for Prettier takes a significant amount of time. I have been unable to find a solution thus far (I tried some solutions like uninstalling some packages etc., but no luck).

The closest thing I found that relates to this issue is this GitHub thread without a solution: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48748

If you happen to discover a solution to this problem in the future, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share it here.

Comment: After reading some suggestions from this thread:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38477#discussioncomment-6148276

I try to uninstall ``prettier-plugin-tailwindcss`` package and luckily my project is working smoothly now

Comment: Thanks, I tried that also, but no luck. I started again with the 13.4.7 with a clean project without any packages like prettier, it's a little better, but still when I spend much time in app development mode, it starts to slow down. I don't know, but I think I miss React Vite development.

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using Any of these VScode extensions mentioned below just uninstall it.. and try, It worked for me .**

- Auto Import
- Auto Import - ES6, TS, JSX, TSX
- Auto Import - ES6 & TS
- Flutter-Auto-Import

[Screenshot of extensions here..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVvDm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in this link

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50417

"I had this issue with prettier-plugin-tailwindcss version 0.3, downgrading it back to say 0.2.1 with npm install --save-dev prettier-plugin-tailwindcss@0.2.1 and restarting VSCode solve the issue for me"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).